# Change ColumnDefinition style programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

The method below is implemented inside of a custom control. It takes `DataTable  table` as parameter and fills the grid `grdMain` with values from table. Each column of this table should change its color on mouse hover. But when I try to attach style to ColumnDefinition, it throws an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Style object is not allowed to affect the
>   Style property of the object to which it applies.

```
private void DrawGrid(DataTable table)
    {
        // Prepare style to apply
        var gridColumnStyle = GetColumnStyles();
        foreach (var column in table.Columns)
        {
            var columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
            columnDefinition.OverridesDefaultStyle = true;

            // System.ArgumentException: 'Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.'
            columnDefinition.Style = gridColumnStyle;
            grdMain.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);
        }
        int rowNumber = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            grdMain.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < table.Columns.Count; columnNumber++)
            {
                var cellText = new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = row[columnNumber].ToString(),
                };
                grdMain.Children.Add(cellText);
                cellText.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
                cellText.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columnNumber);
            }
            rowNumber++;
        }
    }
```

How can I programmatically apply styles to the column definitions?

**UPD:** Here is the implementation of `GetColumnStyles()`:

```
private Style GetColumnStyles()
    {
        var columnStyle = new DataVisualizer.Desktop.Views.Styles.ColumnSelectionTableStyle();
        var columnHoverBrush = columnStyle["ColumnHoverBrush"];
        var columnBrush = columnStyle["ColumnBrush"];

        DataTrigger columnMouseHoverTrigger = new DataTrigger()
        {
            Binding = new Binding("IsMouseOver"),
            Value = true
        };
        columnMouseHoverTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter()
        {
            Property = StyleProperty,
            Value = columnHoverBrush
        });
        var gridColumnStyle = new Style();
        gridColumnStyle.Triggers.Add(columnMouseHoverTrigger);
        return gridColumnStyle;
    }
```

`ColumnSelectionTableStyle` is defined in the separate file:

```
 <ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="DataVisualizer.Desktop.Views.Styles.ColumnSelectionTableStyle"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardSolidColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StandardLinearGradientBrush" StartPoint="0.0,0.0" EndPoint="1.0,1.0">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColumnHoverBrush" Color="BlueViolet" Opacity=".5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColumnBrush" Color="White" Opacity="1"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Is gridColumnStyle an array or a style itself? I might be wrong but you probably have to apply a gridColumnStyle[0].Style

Comment: It's the style itslef. There is no error or even warning until I run the code.

Comment: @ArliChokoev You can't set the `Style` property in the setter of a `Style`. That's what the error message tells you.

Comment: @mm8 how do I apply the Style then?

Comment: @ArliChokoev: What style do you want to apply to what element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a more complex problem than I expected. Here we go.

If I understand this correctly, you're storing various `Brush`es in the class `ColumnSelectionTableStyle` which inherits from `ResourceDictionary`. You then want to use those `Brush`es to create a `Style` for the columns of a `Grid`.

## The Exception (Not Very Important)

The part of your code that's directly causing the exception is the line `Property = StyleProperty` inside `GetColumnStyles`. As the exception says, you can't use a `Style` to change which `Style` is being used (that would create some weird paradox). The reason that's not very important here, is that's not actually what you want to do.

## The Problem with `ColumnDefinition`

If I do understand, that `Trigger` only needs to set the *background* of the column, not change its entire `Style`. Normally I would suggest you have the `Trigger` target the `Background` property, but that's where you run into your real problem. `ColumnDefinition` doesn't have a "Background" property.

`ColumnDefinition` doesn't actually "contain" the elements in that column, it isn't a `Control`, it's not even a visible element. It's used by `Grid` only to manage the layout of its children. If you want a particular column of a `Grid` to have a color, you need to put something in that column which is visible. I'd recommend using a `Border` or `Rectangle`.

## Giving it a Background

To make it appear that your column has a color, add a `Rectangle`/`Border` to the `Grid`, set `Grid.Column` and `Grid.RowSpan` appropriately, and then set the `Background` property of that `Rectangle`/`Border`. I would also set `IsHitTestVisible = false`, since you want the background element to act as if it's not even there. You would then add other elements in the column on top of (not inside of) this background element.

## The IsMouseOver Trigger

`ColumnDefinition` does technically have an `IsMouseOver` property (inherited from a base class), but from what I've tested it doesn't actually work.

`Rectangle` and `Border` do both have working `IsMouseOver` properties, but those only work if the mouse is *directly* over the element (or one of its children) with nothing else in between. Since you are going to be placing addition elements on top of them, those "higher" elements will "steal" the `IsMouseOver`, so the background element won't work as a reliable trigger.

Basically, if you want make the column background change color on MouseOver, you're gonna have to get dirty. The way I see it, you could:

A. Use `MouseMove` or `PreviewMouseMove` events at the `Grid` level to track the position of the mouse, determine which column it's in, and then manually change the `Background` property of the corresponding background element.

B. Listen for changes to `IsMouseOver` at the root element of every cell, then check which column that cell is in and manually change the `Background` property of the corresponding background element.

## TL;DR

Creating a custom control is a lot of work.
You can't use a style to replace itself (but you don't need to).
`ColumnDefinition`s don't have backgrounds, but `Rectangle` and `Border` both do.

Comment: The answer is pretty detailed, thank you. I've already found a way to handle mouse hover, using Rectangles, I'm gonna post it separately.

Comment: However, what kind of paradox would I meet setting the Style to the ColumnDefinition's Style property?

Comment: @ArliChokoev Once a `Style` is removed from an element, the properties set by that `Style` revert to their previous value. So you start with no `Style` applied, then apply `Style` "A", but "A" says to "set `Style` to "B"". So WPF first removes "A" in order to set "B", but once "A" is removed it also removed the command "set `Style` to "B"", which means `Style` would revert back to it's previous value, which is "A". And now we're back where we started trying to apply "A" again.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Keith Stein, the simpliest (and likely the only) workaround is to change the grid column is to use `Rectangle`. In my case, I programmatically add them just above each column and set the `RowSpan` to the number of rows:

```
private Rectangle GetColumnRectangle(int colNumber, int rowsNumber)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Fill = _columnNormal;
        rect.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, colNumber);
        rect.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, rowsNumber);
        rect.SetValue(Grid.ZIndexProperty, 10);


        //Subscribe to events
        rect.MouseEnter += OnColumnMouseEnter;
        rect.MouseLeave += OnColumnMouseLeave;
        rect.MouseDown += OnColumnSelected;
        return rect;
    }
```

The `DrawGrid` method is changed with respect to new method signature:

```
private void DrawGrid(DataTable table)
    {
        foreach (var column in table.Columns)
        {
            grdMain.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }
        int rowNumber = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            grdMain.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < table.Columns.Count; columnNumber++)
            {
                var cellText = new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = row[columnNumber].ToString(),
                };
                grdMain.Children.Add(cellText);
                cellText.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
                cellText.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columnNumber);
            }
            rowNumber++;
        }
        for (int colNumber = 0; colNumber < grdMain.ColumnDefinitions.Count; colNumber++)
        {
            var rect = GetColumnRectangle(colNumber, rowNumber);
            grdMain.Children.Add(rect);
            //Dictionary; indicating whether the column is selected
            _rectangles.Add(rect, false);
        }
    }
```

The first idea to mark column as selected is surely to extend `Rectangle` to add a `Selected` property, but it's `sealed`, so the simpliest solution is a dictionary.
In my case, the styles applied in `OnColumnMouseEnter`, `OnColumnMouseLeave` and `OnColumnSelected` contain have different opacity values, which allows the `Rectangle` act as if these were in the background.

If you need a solution with rectangles behind the columns, you should use Keith Steins solution.

Comment: I don't think that would work if you had an interactive element inside the control. If you had a `Button`, for example, and tried to click it, you wouldn't be able to because the `Rectangle` would be in the way. But it looks like you only have `TextBlock`s, so you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, it's solution only for the cases, when you don't need an element behind this `Rectangle`